# How to migrate a database programmatically? prisma

Tags: prisma

I'm planning to create a secondary database for testing purposes. As of now I'm using [Prisma's Client](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client) to perform CRUD to my secondary database. Good thing it worked fine.

My problem is the migration part. I still need to do it manually. Like editing the `schema.prisma` file, change the database url, and run `prisma migrate dev` manually.

I already browsed to Prisma's github, but I can't find an exact solution. I would like to ask here, maybe someone has an idea on how to achieve it.

---

Working code below.

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  datasources: {
    db: {
      url: 'postgresql://capstone:capstone@postgres:5432/blogpost_test?schema=public'
    }
  }
})

export default prisma
```

I expect something like below, in which we can just migrate the database programmatically??

```
prisma.$migrate or prisma.migrate()
```

Comment: Prisma doesn't support that. the best you can do is to automate running the script via some `child_process` command, but it sure is messy.

I'm moving away from Prisma to Sequelize now. Its much more powerful and sophisticated.

Answer (score 3):

This is not directly supported by Prisma. There is an open feature request that you could +1 [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/13549).

Best workaround for now would be to writes scripts that use the CLI commands.